# bitbake how to disable do_fetch function for particular recipe

Tags: bitbake

In bitbake disable downloading the module from repository every time i compiles the module. compile the module not download it everytime.
tried using noexec flag in the recipe but it didn't help.

Regards
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

`bitbake` usually caches downloads in `${DL_DIR}` (which defaults to `${TOPDIR}/downloads`.

If it *always* downloads a particular component you must be either

- changing the `SRC_URI` in the recipe
- changing something else significant in the recipe
- using something like `HEAD` in the `SRC_URI` which is changing between builds.

It might help if you posted the recipe.

See the documentation for `DL_DIR` [here](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.4/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-DL_DIR)